# Alter Excel Display with excel document

Tags: excel, vba

I have developed an excel document that I want users to view with specific excel display properties (e.g. full screen, ribbon minimized, etc.). Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

fullscreen:

```
Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
Application.CommandBars("Full Screen").Enabled = False
```

rbbon minimised:

```
Application.CommandBars.ActiveMenuBar.Enabled = False
```

however, these will not be affected until the user clicks enable macros.